# Print single data of a psql query inside a loop to stoud

Tags: bash, postgresql, loops, stdout, psql

I have a comma separated csv file. Simplifying it looks like the following:

```
uuid,other_data # this one is not presented, just the data
uuid1,other_data1
uuid2,other_data2
...
uuidN,other_dataN
```

And I am looping it in a bash script it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read uuid other_data
do
    echo $uuid
done < $1
```

Now I would like to perform a psql query with `-c` option inside the loop and, for the moment, just printing the result. But I need the *data*, not the complete psql output. Ie, the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read uuid other_data
do
    psql -h <host> -p <port> -U <user> <database> -c "select some_column from some_table where uuid='$uuid'"
done < $1
```

... will result in something like this:

```
  some_column  
---------------
 8410043071264
(1 row)

  some_column  
---------------
 8410069001030
(1 row)
```

How can I get only the values? (8410043071264, 8410069001030). And will I be able to load it in a variable to do something with it inside the loop? This doesn't work, but you get the idea: inside the loop `some_column=$(psql -h <host> -p <port> -U <user> <database> -c "select some_column from some_table where uuid='$uuid'")` and then `echo $some_column`

Comment: The _fine manual_ for psql says: `-t Turn off printing of column names and result row count footers, etc. This is equivalent to the \t command.`

Comment: Really good point, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try -t option as below;

```
psql -h <host> -p <port> -U <user> <database> -t -c "select some_column from some_table where uuid='$uuid'"
```

> Tuples only (no header/footer): -t

Comment: Yes, exactly as @Ctx suggested. And even `some_column=$(psql -h <host> -p <port> -U <user> <database> -t -c "select some_column from some_table where uuid='$uuid'")` is working fine. Thanks!